# Running two asp.net core applications with docker-compose under the same domain name but different ports using NGINX config

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have 2 asp.net applications running with docker-compose. I want to know like how is the Nginx config works for 2 applications. I need to run both applications under the same domain name but just different ports in https. For example:  I need to access them for app 1 using https://localhost:5000 then for app 2 using https://localhost:5001. Then how the load balancing works of nginx for having 2 applications too. My ask is how is the configuration works for nginx.config?